# Printer Error `Waiting For Paper To Be Loaded` while printing crystal report in c#

Tags: c#, printing, crystal-reports

I am fade up from this error. I am printing a receipt on a button click. But when command goes to the default printer, it show's the following printing error.
[image]

There is no error in printing with other applications. I am using c# with MS-Access Database. Following is my code for printing

```
//Button Click Code
    public void PrintOPDReceipt()
            {
                string ReportPath;
                using (ReportDocument rptDc = new ReportDocument())
                {
                    using (OleDbConnection Con = Connections.Create())
                    {
                        Con.Open();
                        using (DataSet OPDDataSet = new OPDDataSet())
                        {
                            DataTable Dt = new DataTable();
                            Dt.Columns.Add("Query", typeof(string));
                            Dt.Rows.Add("select * from OPDRegistration where Id = " + SetId + "");
                            Dt.Rows.Add("select * from CompanyIdentity");
                            Dt.Rows.Add("Select * from ConsultantMaster where Id = (Select ConsultantId from OPDRegistration where Id = " + SetId + ")");
                            using (DataSet Ds = GetPrintDetails(Dt, Con))
                            {
                                OPDDataSet.Tables["OPDRegistration"].Merge(Ds.Tables[0]);
                                OPDDataSet.Tables["CompanyIdentity"].Merge(Ds.Tables[1]);
                                OPDDataSet.Tables["ConsultantMaster"].Merge(Ds.Tables[2]);
                                ReportPath = Environment.CurrentDirectory + "\\Reports\\rptOPDReceipt.rpt";
                                rptDc.Load(ReportPath);                            
                                rptDc.SetDataSource(OPDDataSet);
                                rpvReportViewer.ReportSource = rptDc;
                                rpvReportViewer.Refresh();                                                     
                                rptDc.PrintToPrinter(Convert.ToInt32(Connections.GetGlobalSettings.Rows[0]["ReceiptPrintCopies"]), false, 0, 0);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

//This  how I am getting data from the database
 private DataSet GetPrintDetails(DataTable dt, OleDbConnection Con)
        {
            string Query = string.Empty;
            using (DataTable NewDt = dt)
            {
                using (DataSet ds = new DataSet())
                {
                    foreach(DataRow Rw in NewDt.Rows)
                    {
                        Query = Rw[0].ToString();
                        using (OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(Query, Con))
                        {
                            using (OleDbDataAdapter adp = new OleDbDataAdapter())
                            {
                                using (DataTable DataDt = new DataTable())
                                {
                                    adp.SelectCommand = cmd;
                                    adp.Fill(DataDt);
                                    ds.Tables.Add(DataDt);
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    return ds;
                }
            }
        }
```

**Note** There is no problem with Printer because it's working fine with other applications.
Any help will be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Try to set the paper size before rpvReportViewer.Refresh(); 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.reporting.webforms.reportviewer.setpagesettings

Comment: @AntónioCampos Thanks for your comment but it's not working.